# Boost installation on windows and mingw

Tags: c++, windows, boost, mingw, codeblocks

I downloaded the zip file of this page: http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.55.0/ to install Boost 1.55.0 in my computer (I use Windows 7) and I unpacked it in C:\boost_1_55_0.

But, I didn't know how to install it, so I found this page: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/bbv2/installation.html

When I type in cmd `.\bootstrap.bat` it show this message:

`Building Boost.Build engine`

`"cl" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable`

`Failed to build Boost.Build engine`

Then i try with `bootstrap.bat mingw` in cmd, it showed me this message:

`Building Boost.Build engine`

`"gcc" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable`

`Failed to build Boost.Build engine`

I don't know what to do.

Additional info:

I use Code::Blocks 13

Mingw is in `C:\Archivos de programa\CodeBlocks\mingw`

Comment: Look at my answer here maybe it helps [build boost](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17888105/1322642) and [build boost](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16263994/1322642).

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to build boost using the visual studio compiler.  You need to use the G++ compiler under mingw.

[Here are the instructions.](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=BoostWindowsQuickRef#Build_Boost)